# SQL Server DDL "error Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the follow DDL query,

```
query failed: 
CREATE TABLE "auxilio_saude_v2"."Solicitacao" 
(
  "IdSolicitacao" int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
  "Descricao" varchar(-1) NOT NULL, 
  "Estado" varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  "MotivoRecusa" varchar(255), 
  "BeneficiarioDboIdVinculo" int NOT NULL, 
  "CadastroDboIdVinculo" int NOT NULL, 
  "CadastroData" datetime CONSTRAINT "DF_cd6a13f4e589eeff45ef3b3a8ea" DEFAULT getdate(), 
  "InicioData" datetime CONSTRAINT "DF_4ae713eccf3d4346f40d25c8fe1" DEFAULT getdate(), 
  "FinalData" datetime, 
   CONSTRAINT "PK_348326c6affdf7e7d271ac6d672" PRIMARY KEY("IdSolicitacao")
)
```

But, it's giving me an error when exectuted:

```
ErrorMessageToken {
  name: 'ERROR',
  event: 'errorMessage',
  number: 102,
  state: 1,
  class: 15,
  message: "Incorrect syntax near ')'.",
  serverName: 'SRVALDESENV',
  procName: '',
  lineNumber: 1
}
```

I'm no seeing the problem. Could somebody help me?

Comment: What is `varchar(-1)`?  I am not familiar with negative string lengths.

Comment: "-1" is what the system tables store for a "max" column length. If you intend to derive DDL dynamically from the system tables, you will need to interpret the values correctly.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for that.

Comment: I suggest better names for your constraints than things like `PK_348326c6affdf7e7d271ac6d672` for your Primary Key; that name doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @VictorSchinaider `varchar(max)` for a description would be a very bad idea. That's meant for text longer than 8K, potentially GB-sized. It's stored differently and is more expensive to read and update

Comment: @Larnu good point.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for the tip. Where can i find the docs about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of this line of your code:

```
  "Descricao" varchar(-1) NOT NULL,
```

You can not use a negative value for `varchar.`

This is the syntax of `VARCHAR` :

```
varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
```

Use n to define the string size in bytes and can be a value from 1 through 8,000 or use max to indicate a column constraint size up to a maximum storage of 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).

[Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `max` doesn't just mean `store anything`. It's stored differently and is more expensive to retrieve or update

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But the question is not about careful data analysis, schema design, and selection of the most appropriate datatypes. That's a comment for OP.

Comment: @SMor I disagree. If something has implications the answer should make this clear. I already found 3 questions today caused because someone copied an answer's code without considering the implications. Adding a warning only takes 1 line